# How can i manage environment specific properties with google cloud appEngine springboot project?

Tags: google-app-engine, properties, runtime-configuration

Documentation says that Google RuntimeConfig Service is one way to do so but I couldn't find any sample around it. Has anybody ever tried that? Any pointer would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup another service using 'spring-cloud-config-server' dependency and then using 'spring-cloud-starter-config' in this gcp appengine project to manage configurations for different environment.